# Handling two redirects in one htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In my domain I have htaccess file to create rewrites. Now, I am rewriting my domain to some other url as follows,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com:8080/$1 [P]
```

Now I want to make example.com/desc to rewrite some folder in the example2.com:8080. Now my htaccess looks like below,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com:8080/$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/desc$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com:8080/myapp$1 [P]
```

I am getting 404 error while hitting `example.com/desc`.

How to get this working with both.

### Edit

Followed the answer from anubhava as follows

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(desc(?:/.*)?)$ http://example2.com:8080/myapp/$1 [P,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com:8080/$1 [P]
```

`example.com` works fine. but `example.com/desc` shows following error  404 error, `desc` is also added in error message.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /myapp/desc
```

Comment: yes.. its working fine'

Comment: I don't want to hit `example2.com:8080/desc` I want to hit `example2.com/desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments above you can try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^desc(/.*)?$ http://example2.com:8080/myapp$1 [P,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com:8080/$1 [P]
```

You can

Comment: Thanks for notified. Edited my question. When I hit `example2.com/desc` in browser I want rewrite to `http://example2.com:8080/myapp/`

Comment: Sorry anubhava, its just copy paste mistakes. I apologise for this. I want to show visitors `example.com/desc` - it needs to go to `http://example2.com:8080/myapp/`

Comment: if user enters `example.com` then it need to go to `example2.com:8080`. thanks for your patience

Comment: Thank you very much anu... Its totally working perfect... Sorry for little delay as I went to meeting... Thank you again..